# Fast multi select MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm searching for a method to query 2.704 MySQL selects in a fast way.
At the moment this queries need 202.91903 seconds, what is too slow.

What is the best way to do so many queries?

**Why I need this?**

I have 26 tables with entries from 24.11.2016 until today. Every minute there is a new entry. (time 10:00am until 04:00am - next day).
Now I need to select the newest entry of each day, but the latest entry could be at 04:00:00 but it also can be earlier (ex. 03:00 pm) I never know when the last entry was.
So I have following select:

```
SELECT `column1`, `column2`, `column3`
FROM `table` 
WHERE `timestamp`>='2016-11-24 10:00:00' AND `timestamp`< '2016-11-25 04:01:00' 
ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

This select I make for every day and for every table.

Does anyone have a solution to speed this up?

Comment: Use Explain in your query

Comment: Where does 2.704 figure come from?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I generate it dynamically with PHP.

Comment: Try to understand the question and don't give such a blunt answer. WHY you're generating 2.704 queries dynamically with PHP?

Comment: @jeroen sometimes the service not sending data or the service is down or there are only data for some hours (Only when someone is working there a new data)

Comment: @YourCommonSense I don't have an idea to get my data in another way

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do, but if you need a small selection of static records from different tables, you should probably copy the new records daily to a new table to use for your analysis.

Comment: So you have to ask here to get an idea. Obviously, the number of queries is the key problem here.

Comment: "Every table" eh? Surely there's only 1 table !?!!!?

Comment: @Strawberry he mentioned 26. Which is also a big question.

Comment: 2.704 implies you're querying all 26 tables for the past 104 days? If so you can speed up by doing `GROUP BY` and (maybe) speed up more by doing a `UNION ALL` for all 26 queries, though this does sound like a "you need to rethink your strategy from the bottom up" sort of a situation.

Answer (score -3):

create an index on your table for column timestamp. When your table rows is growing big, index will be require for it to search for your record fast. without index, it will be like you are searching for row 1 to the row you are looking for in million of rows.

Sample
create index index_name on table_name (column_name)

Answer (score -4):

If i get you right...
I think you could change yours to this

```
SELECT `column1`, `column2`, `column3`
FROM `table`
WHERE date_format(`timestamp`,'%d/%m/%Y')=date_format(curdate(),'%d/%m/%Y')
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1
```

I am using `timestamp` and curdate() to select only the today records, order them by `timestamp` descending, so earlier will be on top and limit the rows to 1 so you will have only the earliest.

Comment: You're just showing a way to format the query, while not addressing the issue at hand.

Comment: But what made you to try? Why did you wait 11 months and then all of sudden decided to answer this one?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I didn't wait for 11 months. In fact I had asked some questions in here that never get a proper answer or I found the answer on my own after a day or so. In both cases my questions got deleted. EDIT: Also many of my questions already had been asked here.